HttpClient request timeout without any exception .NET 8
In a Blazor Server app on .NET 8, I send an HTTP request to an external server, and I do not receive a response based on the specific timeout, based on the behavior I have seen from HttpClient before, I expected

TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled

but nothing happens.
private async Task<HttpResponseModel> PostAsync(string url, object request)
{
      httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(35);
      var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(address, request);
      return await GetResponseResult(response);
}

But if I change the code above, which is a non-blocking code, to a blocking code, the exception I expect will occur:
private async Task<HttpResponseModel> PostAsync(string url, object request)
{
      httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(35);
      var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(address, request).Result;
      return await GetResponseResult(response);
}

Update based on this comment

How are you calling this code?

HttpClientService.cs
public class HttpClientService(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseModel> PostAsync(string address, object request)
    {
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(35);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(address, request);
        return await GetResponseResult(response, request);
    }
}

SmsService.cs
public class SmsService(HttpClientService httpClient) : ISmsService
{
    public async Task<SendOtpResul> SendOtpAsync(SendOtpRequest request)
    {
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("[addrees]", request);
        //...       
    }
}

component code
@inject ISmsService SmsService

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var result = await SmsService.SendOtpAsync();
}

Di registration code
services.AddHttpClient<HttpClientService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("[base address]");
});

services.AddScoped<ISmsService, SmsService>();

I simplified the code as much as possible, maybe my question was not clear because one of the answers was that it can be handled by try/catch. yes, I can. But my question is what is the difference between these two codes, one causes Unhandled Exception and the other does not.

How are you calling this code?

so, keep in mind HttpClient in Blazor (esp. the client side one) is different from the good old HttpClient in desktop/server (form, aspnet, etc) oriented applications. it can stuck due to CORS policy on preflight, so double check on your browser console see if the request actually runs.

But have you actually looked at the response.Exception property? Because in the await version, that's where it'll end.

@BagusTesa  I'm using blazor server which uses signalr not http requests

Not the client side. What actually calls the PostAsync function on the server side?

@Charlieface as you can see SmsService calls  PostAsync  method

@Charlieface In blazor server, the client side term  has no meaning because all requests are processed on the server

In the first code, the httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync() method is called asynchronously, and when a timeout occurs, the await operation will throw a TaskCanceledException. From the documentation, we can learn that: If the exception is not handled, the exception will be treated as an unhandled exception, and when an unhandled exception occurs, the framework will terminate the circuit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#unhandled-exceptions-for-circuits

In the second code, the .Result property blocks the current thread until HttpClient completes the request and returns the result. If the request times out, an exception is thrown directly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-8.0#remarks
And you can check whether the corresponding access endpoint path is correct and try to extend the corresponding timeout time to test whether the data can be obtained correctly.

@YuningDuan I also know what you said above, I think you did not read my question well. In terms of behavior, these two codes should have the same behavior, the only difference is in their sync and async mode, but in async mode, this does not happen, unhandled exception does not occur.

You can use try/catch to catch exception ,Here is an example you can refer to:
private async Task IncrementCount()
{
    try
    {
        currentCount++;
        await PostAsync("https://localhost:7234/Home", new { data = "test" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
           
        Console.WriteLine($"Error in IncrementCount: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


private async Task<HttpResponseModel> PostAsync(string url, object request)
{
        
        Httpclient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        var requestWithExtraContent = new
        {
            originalRequest = request,
            extraContent = "aa"
        };
     var response = await Httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, requestWithExtraContent);
        
        return await GetResponseResult(response);
       
}

Relevant exception will be caught:



Thanks for the answer , but my question is not about handling the exception
